# Инициализация переменной-массива

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть файл News.php, в котором содержится метод getNewsList() класса News:

```
public static function getNewsList() {

     $db = Db::getConnection();

    $newsList = array();

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items_preview ORDER BY date");
    foreach ($result as $res) {

        $newsItem = [
            'date' => $res['date'],
            'title' => $res['title'],
            'image' => $res['image_url']
        ];

        array_push($newsList, $newsItem);
    }

    return $newsList;
```

Также есть файл index.php, в котором есть

```
  include_once ROOT . '/models/News.php';
```

И также есть контейнер

```
       <div class="container_photos">
            <?php foreach($newsList as $newsItem):?>
            <div class="post"><?php $newsItem['image']?></div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
```

Мне необходимо вывести список фото-превью из MySQL в контейнер container_photos, однако проблема в том, что html.php напрочь отказывается инициализировать $newsList из файла News.php, прошу помощи

Comment: А где вызов функции `getNewsList()` ?

Comment: Вызвал, инициализировал, помогло, теперь другая проблема - index.php не отображает $newsItem['image'] как картинку, при вызове print_r($newsItem['image']) , путь к картинке показывает, но фото отобразить не получается, просто пустое место

Comment: Потому что для отображения картинок используется тег `img`. Пора бы уже прочитать книжку по html